# GridView : Template field

Tags: asp.net, gridview

is it possible to create a template field with link option using codebehind.

Comment: It looks like ASP.NET, but please use the correct tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
Append handler OnRowDataBound

```
MyRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
            e.Row.Controls.Add(new MyControl(...
```

Comment: how to add this field using codebehind

<a onclick='javascript:window.open("<%# "sample.aspx?ID="+ Eval("ID")%>","",",width=280,height=200,target=_Blank")'  href="#"> Details</a>

Comment: var hl = new HyperLink();
hl.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:window" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID")...

 e.Row.Controls.Add(hl)